# pasar datos linea por linea de un TextBox a datagridview en c#

Tags: c#

me surgió  el siguiente  problema,necesito  pasar los datos mi **TextBox1** multilinea los cuales consisten en (NOMBRE,ID,TELEFONO) separados por una coma.

ejemplo:

Miguel, 80511164, 5623521212

carlos, 21512412, 2541236521

luis,   12325124,   2136541232

Deseo pasar estos datos a  cada columna de una **datagridview** (NOMBRE-ID-TELEFONO), espero dejarme entender,estare muy agradecido cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Pero cuál es el problema? ¿El `string.Split` para separar por coma, el `Trim` posterior para sacar posibles espacios, o la carga en el `DataGridView`? Te recomiendo [leer esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu consulta. Deberías poner cómo es tu código, qué intentaste hasta ahora, etc.

Comment: el problema es que no se como hacerlo, estoy aprendiendo a  programar,gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de llenar un `DataGridView`, una sencilla es utilizando un `DataTable` como origen de datos. Hay muchas páginas que te explican cómo hacerlo. Por ejemplo, [ésta](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/0f717cea-4b93-4773-891e-fcfa98d1a0e2/como-llenar-un-datagridview-con-datos-de-textbox-c).

Una forma de hacerlo sería así:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataTable dt;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre");
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Telefono");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var line in textBox1.Lines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                continue;

            var valores = line.Split(',');
            if (valores.Length != 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"No se pudo cargar esta línea: \"{line}\"");
                continue;
            }
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Nombre"] = valores[0].Trim();
            row["ID"] = valores[1].Trim();
            row["Telefono"] = valores[2].Trim();
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Como verás, ignora líneas vacías y si no hay exactamente tres campos en una línea, la ignora y advierte que no pudo cargar esa línea.

Comment: Muchas gracias por darte un tiempo, me sirvió de mucho tu ayuda, saludos.